# regex replace value only keep numbers and limit decimal places to 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following text "2345dsds34.000" and i want the following value '234534.00'. I plan to do this via regex replace but somehow it doesnt limit the decimal places to 2.

I am using this `"2345dsds34.000".replace(/[^\d+(\.\d{1,2})$]/g, '')` but it keeps giving me `234534.000`. How can i force it to limit it to 2 decimal points.

```js
console.log("2345dsds34.000".replace(/[^\d+(\.\d{1,2})$]/g, ''))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) JS Number function

```js
Number( "2345dsds34.000".replace(/[^\d+(\.\d{1,2})$]/g, '') ).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply slice the last digit off with `.slice(0, -1)`:

```js
console.log("2345dsds34.000".replace(/[^\d+(\.\d{1,2})$]/g, '').slice(0, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

That regex is targetting the characters between some digits and some other digits having a decimal place.

[image]
   *Snapshot from https://regex101.com/*

Then, the `.replace()` method is removing them. **That all it does.**

Since you don't know how many extra decimal you may have... I suggest you to use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [`.tofixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Please have a look at those two documentation links. ;)

```js
var value = parseFloat("2345dsds34.000".replace(/[^\d+(\.\d{1,2})$]/g, '')).toFixed(2);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Sorry `.toFixed` won't help here, but this `[^\d+(\.\d{1,2})$]` inside character class doesn't makes much sense, there no need of repeating `\d` twice, and also just add `(` in string and you see this doesn't work

Comment: Why? can you explain?

Comment: `parseFloat(str.replace(/[^\d.]+/g,'')).toFixed(2)` will be enough

Comment: I understood that OP was happy about the removal of letters within his number... But wanted 2 decimal places for the result.

Comment: @CodeManiac  Your example will remove the digits... :-/

Comment: It seems to work fine [Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56863529/9624435), can you give any example which is not working

Comment: haa! I did not notice the `^`... ok then. ;)

Comment: @CodeManiac in the scenario whereby i want the user to be able to only input only one `.` character in the string how do i achieve that? I want to be able to replace that only one `.` is in the string and not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
[^\d.]
```

[image]

```js
let str = "2345dsds34.000"
let op = parseFloat(str.replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '')).toFixed(2)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a Regex with capturing parentheses It will look like this

```js
var regex = /(\d{4})[a-z]+(\d{2})\.(\d{2}).*/;
var input_chain = "2345dsds34.000";
var output = input_chain.replace(regex, "$1$2.$3");

console.log(output);
```

Each capturing parentheses can be references in the second part of the `replace` method by their position number prefixed with a `$`